# Converting an awkward xml document structure into a friendly one

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Okay, so I have an auto-generated xml file which represents a certain folder structure in a library:

```
<Folder>
    <Name>One</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>0</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
<Folder>
    <Name>Two</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
<Folder>
    <Name>Three</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
<Folder>
    <Name>Four</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>3</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
<Folder>
    <Name>Five</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
<Folder>
    <Name>Six</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>3</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
<Folder>
    <Name>Seven</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>3</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
<Folder>
    <Name>Eight</Name>
    <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
</Folder>
```

However, I need it to look more human-friendly and less awkward in a following structure:

```
<Folder Name="One">
    <Folder Name="Two">
        <Folder Name="Three">
            <Folder Name="Four"></Folder>
        </Folder>
        <Folder Name="Five">
            <Folder Name="Six"></Folder>
            <Folder Name="Seven"></Folder>
        </Folder>
    </Folder>
    <Folder Name="Eight"></Folder>
</Folder>
```

I have been looking at it for quite a while already and I am lacking any ideas as to how to wrap it into a method. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

So far I have been successfull with putting it into objects of my class, which looks like this:

```
class MyFolder
{
    private List<MyFolder> _folders;
    public List<MyFolder> Folders
    {
        get
        {   if (_folders == null)
            { _folders = new List<MyFolder>(); }
            return _folders;  }
        set { _folders = value; }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Don't know if this leads me anywhere to be honest, I now have a MyFolder which has MyFolders which have other MyFolders etc, hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Why are you using XML for the first case ?

Comment: A client sent it this way. He generated it in MS Project, because I assume it was the only program he could think of in which he could nest elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a console app. It yields what you need. I have wrapped your XML into the FolderTree element just to make parsing easy.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xml = @"<FolderTree>
        <Folder>
            <Name>One</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>0</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>Two</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>Three</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>Four</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>3</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>Five</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>2</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>Six</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>3</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>Seven</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>3</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <Name>Eight</Name>
            <OutlineLevel>1</OutlineLevel>
        </Folder>
        </FolderTree>
    ";

    var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
    var elements = root.Elements().ToList();
    var rootFolderString = GetItemsAtLevel(new Queue<XElement>(elements), 0).First().ToString();
}

private static void TransformElement(XElement folder)
{
    folder.Element("OutlineLevel").Remove();
    var nameElement = folder.Element("Name");
    nameElement.Remove();
    folder.Add(new XAttribute(nameElement.Name, nameElement.Value));
}

private static IEnumerable<XElement> GetItemsAtLevel(Queue<XElement> elements, int level)
{
    while (elements.Any())
    {
        var parent = elements.Dequeue();
        var children = new Queue<XElement>();
        while (elements.Any() && (int)elements.Peek().Element("OutlineLevel") > level)
        {
            children.Enqueue(elements.Dequeue());
        }

        if (children.Any())
        {
            var subtree = GetItemsAtLevel(children, level + 1);
            parent.Add(subtree);
        }

        TransformElement(parent);
        yield return parent;
    }
}
```